# Reading in scientific numbers to gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a column of numbers that are expressed in scientific notation

```
1.00E-05
1.26E-05
   ...
```

I'm really new to gnuplot, so I'm wondering if there's something I need to do to these guys before I can plot them. I'm making a histogram with frequency vs. values (the above numbers) if that's relevant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem reading in that format automatically with gnuplot--I do it all the time :)

Comment: Sweet. Just checking so that I don't inadvertently plot something nutty. Thanks.